# Cannot enable Clean URLs on Drupal after upgrading from 6.12 to 6.15

Tags: drupal, ubuntu, drupal-6, apache2, clean-urls

I have a setup with Drupal 6.12 installed on Ubuntu 9.10.
It took me a while to figure out how to enable the Clean URL...
but after I upgrade from 6.12 to 6.15... the radio on Clean URL was disabled and I tried so many different ways I found from google and drupal.org and was no help...

Can someone please tell me is there is a way to know where the problem is coz one of the problem is it doesn't tell me...

Also I am willing to reinstall the whole thing even the server... if there is upgrade procedure which will ensure the clean url to continue working
or.... if I should install druapl 6.15 from scratch and to make the clean url works, please let me know...

Please understand I am very new to ubuntu and apache and drupal even... My work focus is on the web design and usage but this is really really getting into the way...

Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks a lot.

Cheers

Comment: check your htaccess, it's little changed in 6.15

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure what i should be looking at... the one under my /usr/share/drupal6/ folder? Does it need modification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys...

I was upgrading from Drupal 6.12 straight to 6.15 and it didn't work for me...
then I tried upgrading (using the file only approach) from

6.12 -> 6.13
6.13 -> 6.14
6.14 -> 6.15 and everything works...!

The Enable Clean URL was enabled on every upgrade by default.... don't know why.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your .htaccess file which is in your site root (i.e., the same folder that contains "modules", "includes", "misc", etc.) ...chances are you'll have to uncomment one of the lines near the end.

Answer (score 1):

also check in httpd.conf that AllowOverride set to all All

```
Alias /dtest /xxx/dtest

<Directory "/xxx/dtest">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

    # Drupal - must have AllowOverride set to all All otherwise clean urls does not work
    #  .htaccess line is:  RewriteBase /dtest
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```